# hibernate second level cache can get lazy-loading entity when i set breakpoint

Tags: spring-data-jpa, hibernate-cache

I use Spring data JPA and hibernate second level cache via [hibernate-redis](https://github.com/debop/hibernate-redis) in my project. I use @Transactional for lazy-loading, But it hints miss when I run application. if i debug it, and set a breakpoint wait for some time, it works and retrieve cache from redis. Here is the code:

Entity ItemCategory:

```
@Entity
@Cacheable
public class ItemCategory extends BaseModel {

    @NotNull
    @Column(updatable=false)
    private String name;

    @JsonBackReference
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private ItemCategory root;
}
```

Entity Item:

```
@Entity
@Cacheable
public class Item extends BaseModel {
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private ItemCategory category;
}
```

Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface ItemCategoryRepository extends JpaRepository<ItemCategory, Long> {
    @QueryHints(value = {
            @QueryHint(name = "org.hibernate.cacheable", value = "true")
    })
    @Query("select distinct i.category.root from Item i where i.store.id = :id and i.category.parent.id = i.category.root.id")
    List<ItemCategory> findByStoreId(@Param("id") Long id);
}
```

hint miss:

```
2017-03-06 14:49:30.105 TRACE 30295 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.cache.redis.client.RedisClient       : retrieve cache item. region=hibernate.org.hibernate.cache.internal.StandardQueryCache, key=sql: select distinct itemcatego2_.id as id1_21_, itemcatego2_.create_by_id as create_b8_21_, itemcatego2_.create_date as create_d2_21_, itemcatego2_.last_modified_by_id as last_mod9_21_, itemcatego2_.last_modified_date as last_mod3_21_, itemcatego2_.background_id as backgro10_21_, itemcatego2_.enabled as enabled4_21_, itemcatego2_.name as name5_21_, itemcatego2_.parent_id as parent_11_21_, itemcatego2_.root_id as root_id12_21_, itemcatego2_.slide as slide6_21_, itemcatego2_.son_number as son_numb7_21_ from item item0_ inner join item_category itemcatego1_ on item0_.category_id=itemcatego1_.id inner join item_category itemcatego2_ on itemcatego1_.root_id=itemcatego2_.id where item0_.store_id=? and itemcatego1_.parent_id=itemcatego1_.root_id; parameters: ; named parameters: {id=4}; transformer: org.hibernate.transform.CacheableResultTransformer@110f2, value=[6098054966726656, 3, 1]
2017-03-06 14:49:30.116 TRACE 30295 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.cache.redis.client.RedisClient       : retrieve cache item. region=hibernate.org.hibernate.cache.spi.UpdateTimestampsCache, key=item, value=null
2017-03-06 14:49:30.127 TRACE 30295 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.cache.redis.client.RedisClient       : retrieve cache item. region=hibernate.org.hibernate.cache.spi.UpdateTimestampsCache, key=item_category, value=null
2017-03-06 14:49:41.971  INFO 30295 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] i.StatisticalLoggingSessionEventListener : Session Metrics {
974551 nanoseconds spent acquiring 1 JDBC connections;
0 nanoseconds spent releasing 0 JDBC connections;
0 nanoseconds spent preparing 0 JDBC statements;
0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC statements;
0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC batches;
0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C puts;
19881210 nanoseconds spent performing 1 L2C hits;
24082571 nanoseconds spent performing 2 L2C misses;
0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections);
26331 nanoseconds spent executing 1 partial-flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections)
}
```

if i debug and set a breakpoint wait for some time(not work every time):

```
2017-03-06 14:50:00.565 TRACE 30295 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.h.cache.redis.client.RedisClient       : retrieve cache item. region=hibernate.org.hibernate.cache.internal.StandardQueryCache, key=sql: select distinct itemcatego2_.id as id1_21_, itemcatego2_.create_by_id as create_b8_21_, itemcatego2_.create_date as create_d2_21_, itemcatego2_.last_modified_by_id as last_mod9_21_, itemcatego2_.last_modified_date as last_mod3_21_, itemcatego2_.background_id as backgro10_21_, itemcatego2_.enabled as enabled4_21_, itemcatego2_.name as name5_21_, itemcatego2_.parent_id as parent_11_21_, itemcatego2_.root_id as root_id12_21_, itemcatego2_.slide as slide6_21_, itemcatego2_.son_number as son_numb7_21_ from item item0_ inner join item_category itemcatego1_ on item0_.category_id=itemcatego1_.id inner join item_category itemcatego2_ on itemcatego1_.root_id=itemcatego2_.id where item0_.store_id=? and itemcatego1_.parent_id=itemcatego1_.root_id; parameters: ; named parameters: {id=4}; transformer: org.hibernate.transform.CacheableResultTransformer@110f2, value=[6098054966726656, 3, 1]
2017-03-06 14:50:00.584 TRACE 30295 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.h.cache.redis.client.RedisClient       : retrieve cache item. region=hibernate.org.hibernate.cache.spi.UpdateTimestampsCache, key=item, value=null
2017-03-06 14:50:00.595 TRACE 30295 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.h.cache.redis.client.RedisClient       : retrieve cache item. region=hibernate.org.hibernate.cache.spi.UpdateTimestampsCache, key=item_category, value=null
2017-03-06 14:50:01.805 TRACE 30295 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.h.cache.redis.client.RedisClient       : retrieve cache item. region=hibernate.com.foo.bar.model.item.ItemCategory, key=com.foo.bar.model.item.ItemCategory#3, value={parent=null, lastModifiedDate=2016-12-14 09:30:48.0, lastModifiedBy=1, enabled=true, sonNumber=2, _subclass=com.foo.bar.model.item.ItemCategory, createBy=1, children=3, background=1, slide=0, root=3, name=foo, _lazyPropertiesUnfetched=false, _version=null, createDate=2016-12-14 09:29:56.0}
Hibernate: select user0_.id as id1_59_0_, user0_.create_by_id as create_11_59_0_, user0_.create_date as create_d2_59_0_, user0_.last_modified_by_id as last_mo12_59_0_, user0_.last_modified_date as last_mod3_59_0_, user0_.avatar_id as avatar_13_59_0_, user0_.email as email4_59_0_, user0_.enabled as enabled5_59_0_, user0_.gender as gender6_59_0_, user0_.nickname as nickname7_59_0_, user0_.phone as phone8_59_0_, user0_.seller_auth_info_id as seller_14_59_0_, user0_.seller_auth_status as seller_a9_59_0_, user0_.user_ext_id as user_ex15_59_0_, user0_.user_group_id as user_gr16_59_0_, user0_.username as usernam10_59_0_, user1_.id as id1_59_1_, user1_.create_by_id as create_11_59_1_, user1_.create_date as create_d2_59_1_, user1_.last_modified_by_id as last_mo12_59_1_, user1_.last_modified_date as last_mod3_59_1_, user1_.avatar_id as avatar_13_59_1_, user1_.email as email4_59_1_, user1_.enabled as enabled5_59_1_, user1_.gender as gender6_59_1_, user1_.nickname as nickname7_59_1_, user1_.phone as phone8_59_1_, user1_.seller_auth_info_id as seller_14_59_1_, user1_.seller_auth_status as seller_a9_59_1_, user1_.user_ext_id as user_ex15_59_1_, user1_.user_group_id as user_gr16_59_1_, user1_.username as usernam10_59_1_, user2_.id as id1_59_2_, user2_.create_by_id as create_11_59_2_, user2_.create_date as create_d2_59_2_, user2_.last_modified_by_id as last_mo12_59_2_, user2_.last_modified_date as last_mod3_59_2_, user2_.avatar_id as avatar_13_59_2_, user2_.email as email4_59_2_, user2_.enabled as enabled5_59_2_, user2_.gender as gender6_59_2_, user2_.nickname as nickname7_59_2_, user2_.phone as phone8_59_2_, user2_.seller_auth_info_id as seller_14_59_2_, user2_.seller_auth_status as seller_a9_59_2_, user2_.user_ext_id as user_ex15_59_2_, user2_.user_group_id as user_gr16_59_2_, user2_.username as usernam10_59_2_, usergroup3_.id as id1_65_3_, usergroup3_.create_by_id as create_b5_65_3_, usergroup3_.create_date as create_d2_65_3_, usergroup3_.last_modified_by_id as last_mod6_65_3_, usergroup3_.last_modified_date as last_mod3_65_3_, usergroup3_.name as name4_65_3_ from user user0_ left outer join user user1_ on user0_.create_by_id=user1_.id left outer join user user2_ on user1_.last_modified_by_id=user2_.id left outer join user_group usergroup3_ on user1_.user_group_id=usergroup3_.id where user0_.id=?
Hibernate: select usergroup0_.id as id1_65_0_, usergroup0_.create_by_id as create_b5_65_0_, usergroup0_.create_date as create_d2_65_0_, usergroup0_.last_modified_by_id as last_mod6_65_0_, usergroup0_.last_modified_date as last_mod3_65_0_, usergroup0_.name as name4_65_0_, user1_.id as id1_59_1_, user1_.create_by_id as create_11_59_1_, user1_.create_date as create_d2_59_1_, user1_.last_modified_by_id as last_mo12_59_1_, user1_.last_modified_date as last_mod3_59_1_, user1_.avatar_id as avatar_13_59_1_, user1_.email as email4_59_1_, user1_.enabled as enabled5_59_1_, user1_.gender as gender6_59_1_, user1_.nickname as nickname7_59_1_, user1_.phone as phone8_59_1_, user1_.seller_auth_info_id as seller_14_59_1_, user1_.seller_auth_status as seller_a9_59_1_, user1_.user_ext_id as user_ex15_59_1_, user1_.user_group_id as user_gr16_59_1_, user1_.username as usernam10_59_1_, user2_.id as id1_59_2_, user2_.create_by_id as create_11_59_2_, user2_.create_date as create_d2_59_2_, user2_.last_modified_by_id as last_mo12_59_2_, user2_.last_modified_date as last_mod3_59_2_, user2_.avatar_id as avatar_13_59_2_, user2_.email as email4_59_2_, user2_.enabled as enabled5_59_2_, user2_.gender as gender6_59_2_, user2_.nickname as nickname7_59_2_, user2_.phone as phone8_59_2_, user2_.seller_auth_info_id as seller_14_59_2_, user2_.seller_auth_status as seller_a9_59_2_, user2_.user_ext_id as user_ex15_59_2_, user2_.user_group_id as user_gr16_59_2_, user2_.username as usernam10_59_2_, user3_.id as id1_59_3_, user3_.create_by_id as create_11_59_3_, user3_.create_date as create_d2_59_3_, user3_.last_modified_by_id as last_mo12_59_3_, user3_.last_modified_date as last_mod3_59_3_, user3_.avatar_id as avatar_13_59_3_, user3_.email as email4_59_3_, user3_.enabled as enabled5_59_3_, user3_.gender as gender6_59_3_, user3_.nickname as nickname7_59_3_, user3_.phone as phone8_59_3_, user3_.seller_auth_info_id as seller_14_59_3_, user3_.seller_auth_status as seller_a9_59_3_, user3_.user_ext_id as user_ex15_59_3_, user3_.user_group_id as user_gr16_59_3_, user3_.username as usernam10_59_3_, usergroup4_.id as id1_65_4_, usergroup4_.create_by_id as create_b5_65_4_, usergroup4_.create_date as create_d2_65_4_, usergroup4_.last_modified_by_id as last_mod6_65_4_, usergroup4_.last_modified_date as last_mod3_65_4_, usergroup4_.name as name4_65_4_, user5_.id as id1_59_5_, user5_.create_by_id as create_11_59_5_, user5_.create_date as create_d2_59_5_, user5_.last_modified_by_id as last_mo12_59_5_, user5_.last_modified_date as last_mod3_59_5_, user5_.avatar_id as avatar_13_59_5_, user5_.email as email4_59_5_, user5_.enabled as enabled5_59_5_, user5_.gender as gender6_59_5_, user5_.nickname as nickname7_59_5_, user5_.phone as phone8_59_5_, user5_.seller_auth_info_id as seller_14_59_5_, user5_.seller_auth_status as seller_a9_59_5_, user5_.user_ext_id as user_ex15_59_5_, user5_.user_group_id as user_gr16_59_5_, user5_.username as usernam10_59_5_, authoritie6_.user_group_id as user_gro1_66_6_, authoritie6_.authorities as authorit2_66_6_ from user_group usergroup0_ left outer join user user1_ on usergroup0_.create_by_id=user1_.id left outer join user user2_ on user1_.create_by_id=user2_.id left outer join user user3_ on user1_.last_modified_by_id=user3_.id left outer join user_group usergroup4_ on user1_.user_group_id=usergroup4_.id left outer join user user5_ on usergroup0_.last_modified_by_id=user5_.id left outer join user_group_authorities authoritie6_ on usergroup0_.id=authoritie6_.user_group_id where usergroup0_.id=?
2017-03-06 14:50:01.830 TRACE 30295 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.h.cache.redis.client.RedisClient       : retrieve cache item. region=hibernate.com.foo.bar.model.item.ItemCategory, key=com.foo.bar.model.item.ItemCategory#1, value={parent=null, lastModifiedDate=2016-12-05 09:31:51.0, lastModifiedBy=1, enabled=true, sonNumber=1, _subclass=com.foo.bar.model.item.ItemCategory, createBy=1, children=1, background=1, slide=0, root=1, name=bar, _lazyPropertiesUnfetched=false, _version=null, createDate=2016-12-05 09:31:28.0}
2017-03-06 14:51:02.165  INFO 30295 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] i.StatisticalLoggingSessionEventListener : Session Metrics {
15435533 nanoseconds spent acquiring 1 JDBC connections;
0 nanoseconds spent releasing 0 JDBC connections;
1405433 nanoseconds spent preparing 2 JDBC statements;
2301936 nanoseconds spent executing 2 JDBC statements;
0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC batches;
0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C puts;
64020073 nanoseconds spent performing 3 L2C hits;
27037450 nanoseconds spent performing 2 L2C misses;
1247578 nanoseconds spent executing 1 flushes (flushing a total of 4 entities and 3 collections);
24403 nanoseconds spent executing 1 partial-flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections)
}
```

application.yml:

```
spring:
  profiles: development
  jpa:
    show-sql: true
    properties:
      hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache: true
      hibernate.cache.region.factory_class: org.hibernate.cache.redis.hibernate5.SingletonRedisRegionFactory
      hibernate.cache.use_query_cache: true
      hibernate.cache.region_prefix: hibernate
      hibernate.generate_statistics: true
      hibernate.cache.use_structured_entries: true
      redisson-config: classpath:redisson.yml
      hibernate.cache.use_reference_entries: true
      javax.persistence.sharedCache.mode: ENABLE_SELECTIVE
```